# Trying to combine lists with DateTimeField and date object in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I've got 2 Django query lists with a Title and a Created_At DateTimeField (Articles and Projects), I have another list which is the result of a python function that returns a string Title and a Create_At date object.

I want to chain these lists together so I can combine them and sort the results by their Date fields - however at the moment I'm getting the following error:

```
can't compare datetime.datetime to tuple
```

How do I get these two lists together? The code causing the error is:

```
latest_changes = sorted(
    chain(articles, projects, tweets),
    key=lambda instance: instance.created)
```

**OR** Is there a better way to do this instead of using chain? Ideally I'd like to create a new list without having to have the individual list field names matching as well (I gather chain matches like to like on names).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the tweets.created is a tuple rather than a Datetime object. You can use the dateutil module to convert the tuple into a proper Datetime object in python and then you can compare seamlessly :)

Comment: Thanks, that did the job. I fixed it using `tweet.created = datetime.date.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(rfc822.parsedate(tweet.created_at)))`

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the error message, apparently `instance.created` is a tuple for one of your chained iterables.

My guess is that it's whichever item is the "result of a python function that returns a string Title and Create_At date object" that you were talking about, as a `DateTimeField` wouldn't return a tuple.

Does `type(tweets[0].created) == tuple` return `True`?